# Modelling of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, modeling

I was wondering if there's a way of creating a simple MOSFET model that predicts how the following circuit behaves when voltage source *V* is varied.

[image]

As I understand it, if MOSFET M1 is in the saturation region then the voltage at node *S* is held more or less constant. This is because as *Vds* increases then *Vgs* decreases, meaning that M1 conducts an (almost) constant current.

My question relates about how to construct simple circuit models of the MOSFET to intuitively predict this behaviour. I could solve the non-linear MOSFET DC characteristic equations for different values of *Vds*, but this seems cumbersome and would not scale well to larger, more complex, circuits. I've read up on small signal models of MOSFETs, but they seem to be created at particular bias conditions and then predict how small changes in *Vgs* affect the drain current.

Any help and advice here greatly appreciated. I'm new to this field of electronics and finding it quite hard to get on top of even simple circuits like this.

EDIT:

After some thinking/research, the best solution that I've come up with is the following:

1. Create a small signal model of the MOSFET, using the linearised model consisting of a VCCS in parallel with an output resistance. Updated schematic shown below.

[image]

2. The voltage source *Vgs* is used to control the VCCS *Gm*. The value of *Vgs* is used to adjust the value of *Gm* as the supply voltage *Vs* is varied. *Vgs* is an unknown variable in the solution of the small signal circuit and must be solved for to satisfy the circuit equations. This models the decreasing *Vgs* and *Vs* increases and vice-versa.
3. Note that the values of *Vgs* and *Vs* are small signal values and represent only deviations from the bias point calculated in step 1.

By creating some simple models of the MOSFET using the long channel device equations (see Wikipedia article) I was able to calculate the bias point of step 1. I could then sweep *Vs* and plot the changes in *Vgs* and *VR1* to confirm that the model source potential does not vary much as *Vs* varies. I could then repeat this using the linear, small signal model. The results are below (small signal results on plot on the right):

[image]

As you can see, the results between both models are almost identical (bias point calculations on left are relative to the value of *Vs* used to create the small signal model). I think this must mean that the *Ids* characteristics of the MOSFET at this bias point are near linear.

Please let me know if I've made mistakes here. Not sure if this is a sensible approach to better understanding how MOSFETs behave in circuits or not.

Comment: What sort of model do you want? What nonideal factors do you want to consider? The gold standard is the BSIM suite of models, but that targets state-of-the-art devices at small feature sizes, and I believe are only valid for lateral devices.

Comment: Ideally a very simple model that can be used for hand calculations and to help intuitively understand circuit behavior. For example, small signal models are comprised of a current source in parallel with an output resistance, but those are created at a fixed Vds bias voltage and don't seem to be quite what I'm looking for here (I think)

Comment: Simple FET models are a staple of 2nd year or so EE courses; you should be able to find many resources in that direction.

Comment: *I was wondering if there's a way of creating a simple MOSFET model that predicts how the following circuit behaves when voltage source V is varied.* <-- yes there is but, if you need help implementing it then you need to unambiguously state what your model is intended to do.

Comment: I'm looking for a model similar to the standard MOSFET small signal model. The reason that I don't think the small signal model is applicable here is because it's created at a specific Vds bias point and then predicts changes in drain current as Vgs is varied. I want a model that, at a minimum, can be used to approximate changes in drain current when small Vds changes are applied. From the reading I've done, I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: The output impedance is either from channel modulation effect, or resistance in the triode region.